# Python installing libraries with "pip install" error

Tags: python, pip

**Why I try to install any library with 'pip install {library_name}' I get this error:**

WA

```
RNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/ketboar
d/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/ketboar
d/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/ketboar
d/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/ketboar
d/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/ketboar
d/
```

**I tried reinstalling python and windows, nothing helped.**

Comment: connect to internet, pip won't work without internet

Comment: Do you want to install ketboard module? if that is the case, first check your connectivity and be sure that pypi.org is visible to you (with ping or telnet, etc) then type "pip install ketboard".

Comment: Try adding `--verbose` flag, i.e. run `pip install --verbose {module}`. It will print a lot of details of reason of failure. Maybe you have internet but something other is wrong.